# Angular Material md-select default and after select '$state.go'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-material

I can display the option values but my default value is not working. I also would like to $state.go to work after I select a value from the drop menu.

Within my Constructor:

```
   if (this.showCustomerMenu) {
            this.api.customer.getCustomers().then(customers => {
                this.customerList = customers;
                this.selectedCustomer = 'Default Not Working';
            });
   };
```

My HTML:

```
 <md-select ng-model="viewPackagesCtrl.selectedCustomer" ng-selected="viewPackagesCtrl.selectedCustomer" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}"
   ng-change="viewPackagesCtrl.goToCustomerSelectedPckgs()">
    <md-option ng-value="customer" ng-repeat="customer in viewPackagesCtrl.customerList">{{ customer.name }}</md-option>
 </md-select>
```

NG-Change Method:

```
public goToCustomerSelectedPckgs = () => {
    if (this.showCustomerMenu) {
        this.$state.go(this.APP_STATES.viewPackages);
    }
}
```

Comment: as you said `trackBy: 'id'` you have to set id when you want to preselect value

Comment: The trackBy: 'id' seems to display all values within the selected display. Also, that doesn't help with $state.go which doesn't transition to the next page.

"{trackBy: 'customer.id'}" seems to not update the ng-model...

Comment: "{trackBy: customer.id}"  is working I'm just having trouble now with the 

$state.go....